# Why Do I Have "joinAdInterestGroup" Scriplets and Tracing in My Console After Installing React-Scripts as a DevDependency?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, trace, react-scripts

I reinstalled "react-scripts" (5.0.1) as a devDependency to get around the npm audit false-alarm issue that flags one of its dependencies as a severe vulnerability. Starting after that (as far as I can tell) not only do I get multiple "navigator.joinAdInterestGroup" and navigator.leaveAdInterestGroup" scriplets with tracing running in my console every time I boot up my frontend (see below), but there are also mentions of a "coupang.com" and "coupangcdn.com." What is this, and how can I get rid of it? Thanks.

EDIT: As I looked into this some more, it appears that there is a react-scripts dependency called "jridgewell/trace-mapping," so I don't know if, now as a devDependency, this package is the reason for this console activity? Either way, however, I could not find any association between this package and coupang.com.

```
VM6:206 #%#//scriptlet("set-constant", "navigator.joinAdInterestGroup", "undefined") trace start

VM6:208 console.trace
hit @ VM6:208

VM6:210 #%#//scriptlet("set-constant", "navigator.joinAdInterestGroup", "undefined") trace end

VM6:502 #%#//scriptlet("set-constant", "navigator.leaveAdInterestGroup", "undefined") trace start

VM6:504 console.trace
hit @ VM6:504

VM6:506 #%#//scriptlet("set-constant", "navigator.leaveAdInterestGroup", "undefined") trace end

VM6:798 #%#//scriptlet("set-constant", "navigator.runAdAuction", "undefined") trace start

VM6:800 console.trace
hit @ VM6:800

VM6:802 #%#//scriptlet("set-constant", "navigator.runAdAuction", "undefined") trace end

VM6:1094 #%#//scriptlet("set-constant", "navigator.adAuctionComponents", "undefined") trace start

VM6:1096 console.trace
hit @ VM6:1096

VM6:1098 #%#//scriptlet("set-constant", "navigator.adAuctionComponents", "undefined") trace end

VM6:1390 #%#//scriptlet("set-constant", "Document.prototype.browsingTopics", "undefined") trace start

VM6:1392 console.trace
hit @ VM6:1392

VM6:1394 #%#//scriptlet("set-constant", "Document.prototype.browsingTopics", "undefined") trace end

VM6:1686 #%#//scriptlet("set-constant", "document.browsingTopics", "undefined") trace start

VM6:1688 console.trace
hit @ VM6:1688

VM6:1690 #%#//scriptlet("set-constant", "document.browsingTopics", "undefined") trace end

VM6:1982 ~coupang.com,~coupangcdn.com#%#//scriptlet("set-constant", "PartnersCoupang", "undefined") trace start

VM6:1984 console.trace
hit @ VM6:1984

VM6:1986 ~coupang.com,~coupangcdn.com#%#//scriptlet("set-constant", "PartnersCoupang", "undefined") trace end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though this has an accepted answer, it still doesn't answer why Adguard has to add those scriptlets.

It's to protect against the cynically named "Protected Audience API", which basically runs advertisement auctions on your device. It's part of Chromium now, however most Chromium forks remove it through patches.

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/privacy-sandbox/protected-audience/

Answer (score 1):

Ah heck, apparently this all came from my AdGuard AdBlocker Chrome extension.